# Configure separate port for Jboss Admin Console

Tags: firewall, jboss

We want to configure our jboss server behind a firewall. We want to allow access only to our web application.

Is there any way to configure separate port for jboss `admin-console`, `jmx-console`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use mod_jk_ajp  to map to a Jboss slave, then you can use the JKUnmount  directive to unmount the jboss applications that you dont want served.

So, the rough idea is:

```
JKMount  /myapp   mainworker
JKUnmount /admin-console
JKUnmount /jmx-console
```

Mod_jk, if configured that way, in theory, won't forward requests to JBoss for those unmounted applications.  I haven't tried this though.

This is similar to what some people do with mod_rewrite:

```
# dont proxy files (or app) located at/in: /images /stylesheets /javascripts
RewriteRule "^/(images|stylesheets|javascripts)/?(.*)" "$0" [L]
```